# Altering an immutable object?

Tags: python, reference, tuples, immutability

```
def add_alpha(tuple_in):
    list_out = []
    for t in tuple_in:
        t.append(10)
        
a = ([1,1], [2,2], [3,3])
b = a
print(id(a), id(b))
add_alpha(a)
print(id(a), id(b))
print(b)
```

The above example shows that, even though `a` is an immutable object, we can technically alter its elements. How is that so? Wouldn't it make more sense if `a` was assigned a new id, so that we are not changing `b` as well?

Comment: The a element is immutable (tuple), however not the lists (mutable) inside the tuple. That's why you can change the elements in the lists inside the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate misconceptions here.

##### Tuples can have mutable elements

`a` is immutable with respect to which lists `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[3]` point to.

In other words

```
l = a[0]
# do something (that does not reassign a)
print(l is a[0])
```

will always print `True`.

However, you can still *mutate* `a[0]`. A list cannot know that it is in some tuple and shall now be resistant to mutations.

If you issued

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
t = (l, 'foo')
```

you would expect `l.append(1)` to work fine. (And it does.)

##### Assignment never copies data

Python names work like labels for objects in memory. Assigning another name creates a new label, nothing more. When you issue

```
a = Foo() # some mutable object, or with mutable elements
b = a
mutate(a) # mutate a or one of its elements
```

the change will be seen across all names (`a` and `b`), because there only ever was one mutable object in memory. `a = b` didn't copy anything.